# Jquery append wont show gif animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can someone explain me why i can't show gif image with append.
Here is my code:

HTML

```
<p id="register_p">
<label for="submit"></label>
<input id="register" type="submit" name="register" value="Registracija"/>
</p>
<p>
<div id="reg_js_img"></div>
</p>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#register").click(function(){
       var loader_img = '<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />';
   $("#register_p").hide();
   $("#reg_js_img").append(loader_img);
   });
});
```

Comment: Please show your final HTML (after PHP has executed). That could be the root of your problem...

Comment: That's not just javascript. What Lee said.

Comment: Thats the problem couse div is empty, but when i do alert loaderimg at the end i got ok image tag with property path.

Comment: Xmmm strange, there is image everything is ok, but cant get animation just empty space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an issue with your image URL. See this working fiddle w/ajax loader image coming from Wikipedia. Your code is unchanged.

http://jsfiddle.net/Penfq/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#register").click(function(){
       var loader_img = '<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />';
   $("#register_p").hide();
   $("#reg_js_img").append(loader_img);
   });
});
```

Comment: My image path is ok maybe my browser bugged couse i add this path from wikipedia and its same :(

Answer (score 0):

I just made it :)

```
<div id="reg_js_img"></div>
<p id="register_p">
<label for="submit"></label>
<input id="register" type="submit" name="register" value="Registracija"/>
</p>
```

All what i done is switch div for image above submit, for some reason when js hide submit i cant get animation :(
strange :)